# Could NOT find roscp (missing: roscp_DIR)

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS, and I got errot when trying to make workspace with catkin_make.
Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscp" with any of
  the following names:

    roscpConfig.cmake
    roscp-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307558/could-not-find-roscp-(missing:-roscp_dir)/) by [nyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/38356/nyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you mean `roscpp`?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0